# How to simultaneously assign value to dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

When I have a existing dictionary, I want to simultaneously assign value to it.

Example:

It's a sample about dictionary.

```
people_list = {
    "Tom": None,
    "David": None,
    "Traivs": None,
}
```

I want each of key:value pairs has same value.

This is my wanted result.

```
people_list = {
    "Tom": "hello",
    "David": "hello",
    "Traivs": "hello",
}
```

Except loop-statement, what do I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line:

```
people_list.update(dict.fromkeys(people_list.keys(),"hello"))
```

Comment: Just an FYI, this method is much slower than the other two methods (944 ns per loop)

Comment: I was trying to do it without any sort of loop statement, but it's good to know this information.

Comment: Ah, that's true. There isn't a loop there. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [3]: {key: 'hello' for key in people_list}
Out[3]: {'David': 'hello', 'Tom': 'hello', 'Traivs': 'hello'}
```

Time comparison with @Paul's solution:

```
In [12]: d = dict(zip(range(1, 10000), range(10000,1)))

In [13]: %timeit d2 = {key: 'hello' for key in d}
1000000 loops, best of 3: 240 ns per loop

In [14]: %timeit d.update(dict.fromkeys(d.keys(),"hello"))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 844 ns per loop
```

Comment: Your computer must be faster than mine. :P

Comment: @nivixzixer You should get a mac, sir. :-)

Comment: There's no need to add `.keys()` (which in Python 2 materializes the list).  Iteration over `d` is iteration over the keys anyway.

Comment: a Mac isn't necessarily faster

Answer (score 2):

It's still technically a loop, but you could use an iterator:

```
new_value = None
dict(map(lambda (k,v): (k, new_value), people_list.iteritems()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) if you want a dictionary with same values:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> people_list = defaultdict(lambda: "hello")
>>> print people_list["Tom"]
'hello'
>>> print people_list["Davis"]
'hello'
>>> print people_list["Travis"]
'hello'
```

Key/value pairs are created on-demand.

Comment: I like this answer. It's so clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magical way to simultaneously set all immutable values in a dictionary in the manner that you request without some form of iteration occurring at some level.

Possibly the closest is to use `dict.fromkeys()`:

```
people_list = dict.fromkeys(people_list, 'hello')
```

Although, of course, iteration is still occurring within `fromkeys()`.

If you are happy with a level of indirection, it is possible to have a dictionary with mutable values, e.g. a list, and to update all of those at once:

```
>>> v = [None]
>>> d = {k:v for k in ['Tom', 'David', 'Traivis']}
>>> print d
{'David': [None], 'Traivis': [None], 'Tom': [None]}
>>> v[0] = 'hello'
>>> print d
{'David': ['hello'], 'Traivis': ['hello'], 'Tom': ['hello']}
```

Here there is no loop, but the downside is that the value must be extracted:

```
>>> d['Tom']
['hello']
>>> d['Tom'][0]
'hello'
```